# Excel VBA editing comment if exists

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

My code is checking if cell value from 2 sheets are different, if no it continue check for next row, if different it copy from sheet2 to sheet1 the cell value where I need and add to Cell in sheet1(where the value copied too) a comment with the old value.
every time when the value changed again it remove the comment and put new one.
I need to do a comment check if exist and **append** the old value to comment.
I want that the comment will contain all the old values that changed in the cell.

this is my piece of code:

```
                        If Not IsEmpty(datasheet.Cells(iData, j).Value) Then
                        comm = user & vbNewLine & "Old Date:" & vbNewLine & ActiveCell.Value
                        datasheet.Cells(iData, j).Copy Destination:=ActiveCell
                        With ActiveCell
                            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                            With ActiveCell.Borders
                                .LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Setting style of border line
                                .Weight = xlThin 'Setting weight of border line
                                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'Setting colour of border line
                            End With
                            If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then .Comment.Delete
                                .ClearComments
                                .AddComment
                                .Comment.Text Text:=comm
                                .Comment.Visible = False
                        End With
```

Comment: not much code or context there.

Comment: `ActiveCell`? How do you get the active cell?

Comment: with `.Find`, on sheet2 running on all rows in a column and in sheet 1 I "Find" it, when it founded its the `ActiveCell`

Comment: Is there a question here? You have a code and I assume it works.

Comment: its works just for adding new comment all the time. I asked for editing comments if its exists

Comment: Have you any code that you have already tried - does it work and if not, what errors do you get? Your sample code snippet above already shows that you know how to access comments in a cell and also the comment text. So what, specifically, is it that you are having trouble with?

Comment: I dont know how to change the if statement to check if comment exists and just edit it , or if comment not exists to add new one. every time I tried do something it delete old comment and add new one.

Comment: I have not provided an answer, because this is a "give me the code" type question that is really trivial. You have all the information you need to complete the task. You even know which `If` statement to change. I suggest you research how `If-Then-Else-EndIf` works. And then you will see that a very simple edit to what you already have will give you what you want. As well as the skill and knowledge to do this yourself next time round. This is not a StackOverflow type of problem - this is yourself requiring a tutorial on the fundamentals of programming and the language.

Comment: `                                If .Comment Is Nothing Then
                                    .AddComment
                                    .Comment.Text Text:=comm
                                    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
                                Else
                                    comm = .Comment.Text
                                    Txt = comm & vbNewLine & Txt
                                    .Comment.Text Text:=Txt
                                    .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
                                End If` not edit

Comment: Yes, that looks about right.  In the `Else` part, could simplify to `.Comment.Text Text:=.Comment.Text & vbNewLine & comm`. The first part could simplify to `.AddComment comm `. The `Autosize` element is common to both blocks so can be outside the `If-Then-Else-Endif`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-addcomment-method-excel and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/comment-text-method-excel . Now you can add an answer to your own question :-)